# delete specific xml node Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

My xml file is like:

it contains different 'object' nodes and in different objects there are different parameters one is deleted parameter.

I want to delete the all 'object' nodes that contains the deleted parameter 1.

This is the code that deletes the node object which has a parameter node deleted =1:

```
x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
for(var count=0; count<5;count++){
  var y=x.getElementsByTagName("deleted")[count]; //Find that nodes arent
  if(y.textContent == "1") {
    var z=y.parentNode; //delete the node from the parent.
    x.removeChild(z);
    Xml2String1= new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? where did you stuck?

Comment: your xml, js codeblock isn't showing...

Comment: thanks for the consideration,

I again tried and my method works this is the code that deletes the node object which has a parameter node deleted =1:
"
    x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
    for(var x1=0; x1<5;x1++){
    var y=x.getElementsByTagName("deleted")[x1];
    //Find that nodes parent
    
    if(y.textContent == "1")
    {
    var z=y.parentNode;
    
    //delete the node from the parent.
    x.removeChild(z);
    
    Xml2String1= new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(x);  
"
thanks

Comment: Please change x1 to i or index or something sane

Comment: no i think it works since x1 is the loop variable and it checks for the all nodes that does they carry any deleted 1 so if they have they delete their parent node form the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is incorrect:

```
for(var x1=0; x1<5;x1++){
  var y=x.getElementsByTagName("deleted")[x1];
```

Your loop runs for 5 iterations without regard for the number of `<deleted>` elements are found.  Each time through the loop you search again and get a new [NodeList/HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) of the remaining `<deleted>` elements, but your loop counter is incremented regardless.

Try this instead:

```
var deletedNodesList = x.getElementsByTagName("deleted");
var nodesToDelete = [];
for (var index = 0; index < deletedNodes.length ; index += 1)
    {
    var node = deletedNodes[index];
    if (node.textContent == "1")
        {
        nodesToDelete.push( node.parentNode ); //delete the node from the parent
        }
    }

nodesToDelete.forEach( function() { x.removeChild(this); } );
```

Note that, per the documentation on MDN, the NodeList is a *live* collection, so don't modify it while you are processing it.

---

PS. 
I second raam86's recommendation to use sane (meaningful) variable names.  Meaningful variable names make it easier to understand the code, which makes it easier to write correct code and to resolve problems in incorrect code.

Comment: the loop was set to 5 for the testing purpose.